# Casting from int array to char pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, casting, strlen

```
int v_1[10] = { -1,1000,2 };

int a;

a = strlen(((char*)v_1 + 1));
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the 'a' variable is equal to 5 in this particular case.

I'm also struggling to grasp the behavior of the typecasting to char*. I don't undrstand if the are some calculation for the typecasting that i'm missing because i cannot get 5 in any way.

I attempted to modify the values in the array, but I can't discern what leads to the resulting outcome.

I am working on a Windows platform.

Comment: C character strings are a sequence of non-zero bytes  terminated by a zero byte.  The stlen you get there is from counting the non-zero bytes.  It is also a very dangerous thing to do because if all of the int array bytes are non-zero the strlen function will read past the end of the int array which is undefined behavior.

Comment: What is your expectation what you should get from `strlen`? An `int` array is not a string. The concept of a string length does not apply at all if you do not have a string, to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `a` depends a lot on what system you run this on. Presumably in this case, you're using a system where `sizeof int` is equal to 4, and integers are stored in little-endian.

A simple program can show you the contents of your data in hex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int v_1[10] = { -1,1000,2 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof v_1; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) printf(" "); // add a space every 4 bytes
        printf("%02hhx", *((char*)v_1 + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output (on a system with 4-byte little-endian integers):

```
ffffffff e8030000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Now, your question is about why `strlen(((char*)v_1 + 1));` is equal to 5. To answer that, look at the output again:

```
ffffffff e8030000 
  ^
  This position is (char*)v_1 + 1
```

You can see that `strlen` is going to step over five bytes (`ff ff ff e8 03`) before reaching a NUL byte, which is what delimits the end of a string. And so that is why, on your system, you get the value 5.